# Where does the thread store its data? and how is brought back into the main program

Tags: java, multithreading

I was wondering how a 2 threads work on one method or block? And how does its process the instructions in the method or block? and would 2 threads work simultaneously or in a Round-Robin fashion to access the method or block?

Comment: the work simultaneously, that's why you need lock for shared resources

Comment: every thread has its own stack

Comment: You should understand that the "main program" is also running in a thread.

Comment: You may want to read a little bit more on scheduling and multithreaded environments. The threads have their own stack and work simultaneously (or appear as if to one another in a single-core processor). The problems  arise when they need to share a common resource.

Comment: Multiple threads can execute the same code at the same time. A thread doesn't "own" the code it's executing. It's like multiple people can watch the same television. It's accessing the same data that needs some extra work, i.e. deciding who's going to change the channel.

Comment: I have read that 2 threads dont actually access the method or block together i.e. they would take turns(if not synchronized) like while thread T1 would finish through say half of the block and then the scheduler gives access to the thread T2 and thread T2 would begin its work on the block. Is my understanding correct? Please advise

Comment: That is true if the two threads are executed on the same processor core: only one thread can execute at a time (whatever the code they execute is). But on multi-core machines, two thread can execute the same code concurrently.

Comment: Threads have been around longer than multi-processor computer systems.  Sounds like maybe your information is out of date.  A modern computer can have four, or sixteen, or more than one hundred CPUs, and different threads can run simultaneously on different CPUs at the same time.  Doesn't matter whether they are executing the same instructions or not.  When different threads operate on the same _data_ at the same time, then their actions may need to be `synchronized`.  If they operate on different data, then they need not interact with each other at all.

Comment: Where dos a thread store its data?  One of the defining characteristics of threads is that all of the threads in a program run in the same shared _virtual address space_.  In principle, any thread can see and touch any data that any other thread can see and touch.  In practice, each thread is given its own stack of _activation records_ which is where you find the arguments and local variables for the functions that the thread is executing.  Everything else though (i.e., all of the Objects and arrays in a program) can potentially be shared.